# Request to reopen an old closed question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen

I was about to ask a question on Physics Stack Exchange, but found it had already been asked, and then closed since it was apparently already answered. I have looked at the link that is given as an answer, and I don't see how it answers the question.

[Vanishing partition function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/480622/)

I don't see how the integrand is a total deriviative. The linked answer just says the author can see that it is a total derivative. This isn't helpful for those of us who can't see that.

Comment: I suppose, since you've got 61 rep at the moment, that there is not a "Reopen" button at the bottom of the post (next to "Share", "Edit", etc)?

Comment: I just see: Share
Cite
Edit
Follow
Flag

Answer (score 6):

One option is to flag the question for reopening, which is a privilege that comes before you can vote to reopen questions.

If I were in your shoes, though, I would ask a new question. The way to avoid the dupehammer is to acknowledge that the other questions exist. You do this by linking to them, summarizing what you think they say, and explaining the gap between the other answers and your understanding.